# Scroll to a specific list item in onsen lists

Tags: list, onsen-ui

I have an `ons-list` which contains a lot of `ons-list-item`, by clicking on each item I show `detail` page, when the user taps on `back button` the `detail` page is pop and it gets back to the page which contains the list but the current position is top of the list, since there are many of items user needs to scroll down to find the last item.

Is there any way to scroll the page to the last position it was or jump to a specific item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior depends solely on the browser itself. Some of them will remember the last position and others will not. If you want to force it to show a specific position, you can use the [OnsenUI's postPop event](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Navigationevents) and manage there the scroll with, for instance, [Angular's $anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll). Hope it helps!